# Vertical Demo with Following Line

Tags: html, css

I have a Functional Vertical Menu. On hover state it has a vertical line that changes from same Background color to a specific color, but what I want is to create a line that follows to the selected menu área.

Attached my Actual Code and the GIF example of what I'm trying to Achieve, someone can help me?

HTML

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Example 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Example 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#nav ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    position:absolute; left:200px; top:200px;
}

#nav ul li{display: inline;}

#nav ul li a{
    display:block;
    background:#fff;
    width:200px;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:4px 7px ;
    border-bottom:1px solid #eeeeee;
    border-top:1px solid #cccccc;
    border-left:5px solid #333333;
    color:#333333;
}

#nav ul li a:hover{
    border-left-color:#0099FF;
    color:#0066FF;
    background:#c4c4c4;
}
```

[image: example gif]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this really nice and clean solution (also extendable to an infinite amount of `<li>` items ;)

```js
$('li').hover(function() {
  $(".verticalLine").css("top", $(this).position().top);
}, function() {
  $(".verticalLine").css("top", "0px");
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.nav {
  position: relative;
}

.verticalLine {
  background: coral;
  height: 60px;
  width: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transition: top ease .5s;
  left: 0;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  vertical-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
  <div class="verticalLine"></div>
  <ul>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something else</li>
    <li>Something more</li>
    <li>Aaaand more</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**
This change the hover part to this piece of code if you want to use the click() element:

```
$(".nav2Li").click(function() {
  $(".verticalLine").css("top", $(this).position().top);
})
```

Comment: Ohh thanks @Tim Gerhard this is exactly what I was looking for:D!!

Comment: I'm Glad I could help! :)

Comment: not sure why is not working properly on my version

https://jsfiddle.net/9fuawwnf/ I've adapted it but once I hover on top of one it moves directly to the second, and my nav is not at the very top :( @Tim Gerhard can you explain me? I would love to learn. thanks!!

Also what If i want to change it from hover to click, should I replace only the hover on the function for a click?

Comment: Hi, here's an updated version of your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9fuawwnf/4/ I had to change the starting position from 0 to 16px (beause of padding & margin & stuff) and i also changed the offset.top to position.top (so that you get the relative position corresponding to your parent and not the offset of the item corresponding to the page top.) Please dont forget to +1 this answer if it helped you! I will post an edit of my answer for you if you want click instead of hover

Comment: @Eugene2018 Hi, I modified my post for you and I also added a further explaining comment above this one

Comment: thanks pal!! that solved my issue, now I'm trying to understand it deeply on my side:)! thanks a lot!! @Tim Gerhard

Answer (score 2):

You could use `after` pseudoelement in your ul hidden and the with a simnple transition and jquery you can make it move playing with the `top` property.

like this:

```js
$('.upli').hover(function () {
    $(this).parent('ul').toggleClass('up');
});
$('.downli').hover(function () {
    $(this).parent('ul').toggleClass('down');
});
```

```css
#nav ul{
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style-type:none;
position:absolute; left:200px; top:200px;}

#nav ul li{display: inline;}

#nav ul li a{
display:block;
background:#fff;
width:200px;
text-decoration:none;
padding:4px 7px ;
border-bottom:1px solid #eeeeee;
border-top:1px solid #cccccc;
border-left:5px solid #333333;
color:#333333;
}


#nav ul:after {
  content:'';
  width:5px;
  height:28px;
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  opacity:0;
  top:14px;
  left:0;
  background-color:#0099FF;
  transition: top 0.5s ease;
}
#nav .up:after {
  top:0px;
  opacity:1;
}
#nav .down:after {
  top:28px;
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav">
       <ul class="">
           <li class="upli"><a href="#">Example 1</a></li>
           <li class="downli"><a href="#">Example 2</a></li>
       </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: Good luck with your project even if you are going to have problems with your accepted answer.